# Sorting multidimensional array gives a wrong first item (starting with a P, instead of an A)

Tags: php, json

I've been helped sorting my multidimensional array by using the following code

```
<?php
    $guildname = str_replace(" ", "_", "Mutiny");
    $url = 'http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/guild/frostmane/'.$guildname.'?fields=members';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);

    array_multisort($json["members"], SORT_ASC);

    foreach($json["members"] as $item) 
    {                           
        echo 
        "<tr>
            <td>" . $item['character']['name'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $item['character']['class'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $item['rank'] . "</td>
        </tr>"
        ;
    }
?>
```

Now the strange thing is, that my array sorts correctly, except for the first item.
Check [this image](http://oi57.tinypic.com/qs32aa.jpg) or the list below as an example:

- Petterslayer
- Albatra
- Arrathas
- Bengta
- Biscuits
- ...

Adding SORT_STRING does not work and gives an error.

Comment: Is there an invisible character in front of 'Petterslayer' that might be causing it to be sorted first?

Comment: This is the API: 
http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/guild/frostmane/Mutiny?fields=members
And this is the incorrect player in my sorted list: 
{"character":{"name":"Petterslayer","realm":"Frostmane","battlegroup":"Misery" 
...
There's no invisible characters as far as I can tell?

Comment: Grabbing the raw data and viewing it in hexadecimal, I can confirm there are no invisible characters in the name.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents ('https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/guild/Frostmane/Mutiny?fields=members&locale=en_GB&apikey=*');
$data = json_decode ($json, true);

$entries = $data['members'];

usort ($entries, 'sortByName');

var_dump ($entries);

function sortByName ($entry1, $entry2)
{
        $name1 = $entry1['character']['name'];
        $name2 = $entry2['character']['name'];

        return ord ($name1) - ord ($name2);
}
?>
```

Comment: I couldn't get that URL to work, but using OPs original URL, this code works.

Comment: Note for OP, it seems that because the entry for Petterslayer was missing the `spec` portion of the array, it was getting sorted first. Regardless of that, the array had more dimensions that the sorting function was not taking into account, namely `character` then `name`.

Comment: @Benjam I removed the API key from the URL. That's probably the reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_multisort()` like so:

```
$array = array
(
[Baritone Horn] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Baritone Maintenance
                [Order] => 12
                [CategoryID] => 13849839018
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Baritone Mouthpieces
                [Order] => 13
                [CategoryID] => 13850963018
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Accessories
                [Order] => 11
                [CategoryID] => 13850964018
            )

    ) 

[Alpen Horn] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Baritone Maintenance
                [Order] => 12
                [CategoryID] => 13849839018
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Baritone Mouthpieces
                [Order] => 13
                [CategoryID] => 13850963018
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Name] => Accessories
                [Order] => 11
                [CategoryID] => 13850964018
            )

    ) 
)

array_multisort($array);
```

Comment: So virtually changing my code to simply
'$json = array_multisort($json);'
would have to work? I'm trying it but it doesn't sort my array.
Don't you have to specify an object you want to sort by?

If I 'print_r($json)' it simply outputs '1'

Comment: Yes, in theory, morew can be read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but after using the array_multisort it gives me the following error:
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I'm using the same foreach like before.

Comment: If you want to sort `$a` and `$b` arrays, you can simply do `array_multisort($a);` and `array_multisort($b);`. If you post the code you're trying use use I'll be able to give you an example